# PySpark new column that selects value from a list of integers

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following dataframe in PySpark:

```
|ID    |YearBLT|MinYear|MaxYear|ADP_Range               |
---------------------------------------------------------
|164876|2010   |2004   |2009   |[2004,2009]             |
|164877|2008   |2000   |2011   |[2000, 2002, 2011]      |
|164878|2000   |2003   |2011   |[2003, 2011]            |
|164879|2013   |1999   |2015   |[2003, 2007, 2015, 1999]|
```

Where the YearBLT is the year a property was built, the ADP_Range represents years where building codes were updated, and the MinYear/MaxYear represent the minimum and maximum years of the ADP Range.

I am trying to add a column (ADP_Year) that has the most applicable building code with the following logic:

- If the YearBLT is less than the MinYear, ADP_Year == "NA"
- If the YearBLT is greater than the MaxYear, ADP_Year == Max(ADP_Range)
- If the YearBLT is in between, it chooses the closest date *below* the YearBLT in the ADP_Range

The expected output would be as follows:

```
|ID    |YearBLT|MinYear|MaxYear|ADP_Range               |ADP_Year|
------------------------------------------------------------------
|164876|2010   |2004   |2009   |[2004,2009]             |2009    |
|164877|2008   |2000   |2011   |[2000, 2002, 2011]      |2002    |
|164878|2000   |2003   |2011   |[2003, 2011]            |NA      |
|164879|2013   |1999   |2015   |[2003, 2007, 2015, 1999]|2007    |
```

2010 > MaxYear, so it chooses the value from MaxYear,

2008 is in between 2000 and 2011; since there's a third value of 2002, that is chosen as it is more recent than 2000

2000 < MinYear so it sets it to NA

2013 is in between 1999 and 2015; since there's third and fourth values of 2007 and 2015, 2007 is chosen

The first two cases are simple and I have working code for them:

```
dfADP = dfADP.withColumn("ADP_Year",when(dfADP['YearBLT'] < dfADP['MinYear'], lit("NA")\
.when(dfADP['YearBLT'] > dfADP['MaxYear'],dfADP['MaxYear'])))
```

I'm spinning my wheels on this and would love some suggestions on if this is even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's find maximum of the range

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_max, col, expr, when

max_adp_range = array_max("ADP_Range")
```

and the closest value:

```
closest_adp_range = array_max(expr("""
    filter(ADP_Range, y -> y < YearBLT)
"""))
```

and combine these two into a single expression:

```
adp_year = when(
    # If the YearBLT is greater than the MaxYear, ADP_Year == Max(ADP_Range)
    col("YearBLT") > col("MaxYear"), max_adp_range
).when(
    # If the YearBLT is in between, it chooses 
    # the closest date below the YearBLT in the ADP_Range
    col("YearBLT").between(col("MinYear"), col("MaxYear")), closest_adp_range
).otherwise(
   # If the YearBLT is less than the MinYear, ADP_Year == "NA"
   # Note: not required. Included just for clarity.
   None
)
```

Finally select:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([                                    
    (164876, 2010, 2004, 2009, [2004,2009]),
    (164877, 2008, 2000, 2011, [2000, 2002, 2011]),   
    (164878, 2000, 2003, 2011, [2003, 2011]),         
    (164879, 2013, 1999, 2015, [2003, 2007, 2015, 1999])
], ("id", "YearBLT", "MinYear", "MaxYear", "ADP_Range"))

df.withColumn("ADP_YEAR", adp_year).show()
```

which should give the expected result:

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+--------------------+--------+
|    id|YearBLT|MinYear|MaxYear|           ADP_Range|ADP_YEAR|
+------+-------+-------+-------+--------------------+--------+
|164876|   2010|   2004|   2009|        [2004, 2009]|    2009|
|164877|   2008|   2000|   2011|  [2000, 2002, 2011]|    2002|
|164878|   2000|   2003|   2011|        [2003, 2011]|    null|
|164879|   2013|   1999|   2015|[2003, 2007, 2015...|    2007|
+------+-------+-------+-------+--------------------+--------+
```

Both `array_max` and `filter` higher order function require Spark 2.4 or later. In 2.3 or before you could redefine above expressions as

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

max_adp_range = udf(max, "bigint")("ADP_Range")
closest_adp_range = udf(
    lambda xs, y: max(x for x in xs if x < y), "bigint"
)("ADP_Range", "YearBLT")
```

but you should expect a significant performance penalty (a single `udf` should be faster, but still slower than the native expressions).